# Calling super class from derived class:

Tags: java

when I have created reference object for a subclass and tried to output the reference object, I got output only from the super class and it wont display anything from the sub class. why?

// super class code:

```
public class Employee 
{
    private String name;
    private Date hireDate;

    public Employee()
    {
        name="no name yet";
        hireDate=new Date("January",1,1000);
    }
    public Employee(String theName,Date theDate)
    {
        if(theName==null||theDate==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Error1");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
            name=theName;
            hireDate=new Date(theDate);
    }
    public Employee(Employee originalObject)
    {
        name=originalObject.name;
        hireDate=new Date(originalObject.hireDate);
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public Date getHireDate()
    {
        return new Date(hireDate);
    }
    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        if(newName==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Error2");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else 
            name=newName;
    }
    public void setHireDate(Date newDate)
    {
        if(newDate==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Error3");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else 
            hireDate=new Date(newDate);
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return(name+ " "+hireDate.toString());
    }
    public boolean equals(Employee otherEmployee)
    {
        return((name.equals(otherEmployee.name))&&(hireDate.equals(otherEmployee.hireDate)));
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//sub class code:

public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee 
{
    private double salary; //annually
    public SalariedEmployee()
    {
        super();
        salary=0;
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        SalariedEmployee s=new SalariedEmployee();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}


//Thank u....
```

Comment: What do you mean nothing is displayed from the subclass?

Comment: the above code wont even compile

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println(s);
```

This uses the toString() method of the object. You haven't overridden this method in your subclass, so it's normal that you only see the output from the super class implementation.

For example, you could add in your SalariedEmployee class:

```
public String toString(){
  return super.toString() + ",salary:" +salary;
}
```